# Show window after double click in notify icon (after minimize to tray)

Tags: wpf, notifyicon

I want to use in my wpf aplication notify icon (with .dll library in project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon).

But I don't know, how to show my window (after minimize to tray) by double click in tray icon.

I declared new command

```
namespace MyBasicFlyffKeystroke
{
    class ShowWindowCommand : ICommand
    {
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            Window1 window = new Window1();
            window.Show();
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

And I used it in my window1.xaml file:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="notifyIcon" IconSource="icon.ico" ToolTipText="MyBasicFlyffKeystroke" 
    DoubleClickCommand="{StaticResource ShowWindow}">                    
</tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

and

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <my:ShowWindowCommand x:Key="ShowWindow" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

But after double clicking open new instance with Window1... Is any metod here?

Best regards,
Dagna

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try add an event handler for window messages

**Command**

```
namespace MyBasicFlyffKeystroke
{
    class ShowWindowCommand : ICommand
    {
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            // Broadcast isn't a good idea but work...
            NativeMethods.PostMessage((IntPtr)NativeMethods.HWND_BROADCAST, NativeMethods.WM_SHOWME, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

**In Window1**

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
    source.AddHook(WndProc);
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) {
    if (msg == NativeMethods.WM_SHOWME) {
        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

**And in NativeMethods (UPDATED)**

```
public static readonly int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
public static readonly int WM_SHOWME = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_SHOWME");

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string message);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget RegisterWindowMessage method

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.Current.Window1.Show();
```

this worked for me